# Changes in enqueued / registered stylesheet paths not updating—why?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css, wp-register-style

I'm attempting to modify a WordPress theme so that it appends a version number to a particular stylesheet. This is all done on a local development machine, tested on a staging server, too, for good measure. Following the instructions here:
https://www.mojowill.com/developer/get-your-wordpress-css-changes-noticed-immediately/, I added `filemtime( get_template_directory() . '/css/main.css' )` into the arguments passed through `wp_register_style`

From:

`wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '', 'all');`

to

`wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), 'filemtime( get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css'', 'all');`

No soap. Viewing the source of the rendered page, I see the stylesheet link has no version appended to it.

I tried pulling the `filemtime` function out of the `$ver` slot, and replacing it with a static value like 1.0, and that didn't work, either. Finally, I skipped the `$ver` argument, and changed the path to a versioned file, like so:

`wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css?ver=1.0', array(), '', 'all');`

Still nothing. Why would WordPress refuse to acknowledge these updates? No server-side caching or plugins that I could imagine would influence this process. Is there something very simple I'm missing?

Thanks much

James

edit: Here's the entire relevant code block.

```
function minikit_register_js_and_css() {
    if (!is_admin()) {  
        wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css?ver=1.1', array(), '', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('style');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At long last, I have identified the issue. The theme I was working in used the [Minikit theme starter](https://github.com/stefanolaru/minikit), which has a function that strips version numbers.

`function minikit_remove_wp_ver_css_js($src) {
    if (strpos($src, 'ver='))
        $src = remove_query_arg('ver', $src);
    return $src;
}`

Naturally, the version numbers returned once I stopped calling this function.

Comment: This also affects the [Bones theme starter](http://themble.com/bones/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to [wp_enqueue_style ('unique-style-name' )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style).

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );

function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'unique-style-name', plugins_url( 'my-plugin/css/plugin.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'unique-style-name' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @jgraup. Good thought, but I'm afraid I'm certain I am using `wp_enqueue_style()`. Editing original question.

Comment: It looks like you're hardcoding the version and ignoring the version argument when you register. `function wp_register_style( $handle, $src, $deps = array(), $ver = false, $media = 'all' )` what happens when you remove it from the url and pass the number as an argument?

Comment: `wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');`

Comment: No change. I expected the `$ver` value to be tacked on, so I assumed that passing `''` would mean nothing would be appended to the link URL. Taking the hardcoded version out and using the `$ver` value still doesn't modify the link when the site is rendered:

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/xxxx/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Comment: what happens when you `wp_deregister_script ('style'); wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/xyz.css?ver=youbetterworkorelse');wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );`?

Comment: Or else.... what? Ha, still comes through without the variable. `<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/xxx/css/xyz.css' type='text/css' media='all' />` If I change the file name (ie, 'main.css, xyz.css') the file name changes but the query is lost. What could be stripping the query values?

Comment: Time to format your hard drive and start from scratch. :(

Comment: Install https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ and see if that tells you more.

Comment: Ok, I just reformatted my hdd, and it still doesn't work. :( I guess I'll have to install Query Monitor on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- Try a different identifier other than 'style', make it unique to your plugin, something like 'myplugin_styles'
- Is `wp_head()` called on you `header.php` file? Maybe the stylesheet code is hardcoded on the template.
- Are you running any caching plugins? If so deactivate them.
- This one is trickier, but are you sure this is the only `wp_register_style` declaration on your plugin? Maybe is being set again later on the same file or on another file.

Those are the first ideas that come to mind. I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, @Felix-Chi. Good suggestions.... no luck so far. FWIW, I'm not working with a plugin, just attempting to force WP to increment the version of the theme's main stylesheet.

Comment: Oh ok, same principle applies though, some themes add wp_register_style declarations on the theme files like index.php and page.php instead of functions.php.